# Calling a method with multiple argument

Tags: java, java-stream

I've been using the Java 8 Streams for a while. I came across a situation where I need to stream through a List and pass each element to a method of a class that is not static.

```
List<String> emps = new ArrayList<>();
emps.add("ABC");
emps.add("DEF");
emps.add("GHI");
```

I want to call the "start" method of EmpDataGenerator.

```
EmpDataGenerator generator = new EmpDataGenerator(
                Executors.newFixedThreadPool(emps.size()));
```

I have tried this, but it's not working

```
emps.stream().map(e-> generator.start(e));
```

```
public class EmpDataGenerator {

    // Used to signal a graceful shutdown
    private volatile boolean stop = false;
    private final ExecutorService executor;

    public EmpDataGenerator(ExecutorService executor) {
        this.executor = executor;
    }

    public void start(String name ) {
        Runnable generator = () -> {
            try {
                while (!stop) {
                    //do some processing
                 }
                System.out.println("Broke while loop, stop " + stop);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("EmpDataGenerator thread caught an exception and halted!");
                throw e;
            }
        };
        executor.execute(generator);
    }

    public void stop() {
        stop = true;

        // The shutdown the executor (after waiting a bit to be nice)
        try {
            executor.awaitTermination(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // Purposely ignore any InterruptedException
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
        executor.shutdownNow();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

A `map` must take an input and transform it to something. The `start` method is void.

There is no need for streams here. A simple `forEach` should do.

```
emps.forEach(e-> generator.start(e));
```

or

```
emps.forEach(generator::start);
```

Comment: Is there a way I can use stream here? I understand that there is no need, but I am just curious about the stream implementation of the above case

Comment: `emps.stream().forEach(..)`. Any good IDE will warn you that using stream() is unnecessary here. An acceptable use would be when the start method returns something and you do something with it like `emps.stream().map(generator:start).collect(Collectors.toList())`